# how to send and receive data from JSON on same screen

Tags: php, android, json

I am creating an application in which there is a search screen which takes search data from the user and send them to the server and then the server sends the search result back to the user.

My problem is that i am able to send data but i don't know how to implement receive data in the same class. I have created other application in which their is either send or receive in the same class and but not the both.

I am using json parsing to send/receive data.

In android code, i haven't done the receive part as i don't know how to add the receive functionality with send functionality.

sorry for my bad english.

here is my php server code

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="testdb";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

//$unique_id = $_POST['unique_id'];
$carat1 = $_POST['carat1'];
$carat2 = $_POST['carat2'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$cut1 = $_POST['cut1'];
$cut2 = $_POST['cut2'];
$shape1 = $_POST['shape1'];
$shape2 = $_POST['shape2'];
$stones = $_POST['stones'];


//$query_search = "Select * from search where (unique_id, carat1, carat2, color1, color2 , cut1, cut2, shape1, shape2, stones ) VALUES('$unique_id', '$carat1','$carat2','$color1','$color2','$cut1', '$cut2', '$shape1', '$shape2', '$stones')";
$query_search ="Select * from search where  carat = '$carat1' or carat = '$carat2' and color = '$color1' or color =  '$color2' and cut = '$cut1' or cut = '$cut2' and shape = '$shape1 or shape = '$shape2' and stones ='$stones";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
            $json_output[]=$row;
      echo "search";
    print(json_encode($json_output));

    mysql_close();

//$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;

?>
```

here is my android code.

```
public class QuickSearch extends Activity {

    Button search;
    RadioGroup stones;
    RadioButton single,twin,selected_value;
    EditText to,from,unique_id;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    Intent f1;
    String radiovalue;
    String str_color1,str_color2,str_clarity1, str_clarity2, str_shape1,str_shape2, str_cut1,str_cut2,str_carat1,str_carat2;
    Spinner color1,color2,shape1,shape2,clarity1,clarity2,cut,cut2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quicksearch);

        search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
      //  submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.to);
        from=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.from);
       // unique_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        stones=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        single=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.single);
        twin=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.twin);


        f1 = new  Intent(QuickSearch.this,Search_result.class);





         color1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        color1.setAdapter(adapter);


         color2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        color2.setAdapter(adapter2);


         shape1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shape);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shape, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shape1.setAdapter(adapter3);


         shape2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shape2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter8 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shape2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter8.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shape2.setAdapter(adapter8);



         clarity1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.clarity1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.clarity1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clarity1.setAdapter(adapter4);



         clarity2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.clarity2);
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.clarity2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clarity2.setAdapter(adapter5);


         cut=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cut);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter6 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cut, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cut.setAdapter(adapter6);

         cut2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cut2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cut2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cut2.setAdapter(adapter7);

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {


                   str_color1= color1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_color2= color2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_shape1=shape1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_shape2=shape2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_clarity2=clarity2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                   str_clarity1=  clarity1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_cut1=cut.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_cut2=cut2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   str_carat1=to.getText().toString().trim();
                   str_carat2=from.getText().toString().trim();
                   int selectedId = stones.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                   // find the radiobutton by returned id
                   selected_value = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                   radiovalue= selected_value.getText().toString();




                   dialog = ProgressDialog.show(QuickSearch.this, "","Searching...", true);

                   if(str_color1=="Color To:" || str_color2=="Color  From:" || str_clarity1=="Color To:" || str_clarity2 =="Color From:"
                           || str_cut1 == "Cut To:" || str_cut2 == " Cut From:" || str_shape1=="Shape To:" || str_shape2 =="Shape From"
                           || radiovalue=="" || str_carat1==null || str_carat2==null)
                   {

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
                   else
                   {


                   new Thread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           Search();
                       }
                   }).start();
               }}
           });
    }

    void Search(){
        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/search.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat1",str_carat1.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat2",str_carat2.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("color1",str_color1.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("color2",str_color2.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape1",str_cut1.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape2",str_cut2.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stones",radiovalue.toString().trim()));

            // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Search")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(QuickSearch.this, "Searching Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

               // startActivity(new Intent(QuickSearch.this, LoginScreen.class));
                //f1.putExtra("unique_id", unique_id.getText());
                //st/artActivity(f1);


            }else{
                showAlert();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        QuickSearch.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuickSearch.this);
                builder.setTitle("Searching Error.");
                builder.setMessage("Problem in Searching. Please try again later")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

this is the response from the php server after sending the data from my android phone.

```
8350-8350/com.diamond.traders W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
05-20 13:09:48.841    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders W/SingleClientConnManager﹕ Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
    Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ Response : <br />
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: cut1 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.211    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0550</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>146400</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <br />
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: cut2 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0550</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>146400</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
05-20 13:09:49.221    8350-8434/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Signature Ideal' and stones ='Single' at line 1
```

Comment: It's good practice to use AsyncTask class for interacting with webservices. And create one more method to receive data and call that method whenever you want.

Comment: on button press i did create send method, so should create receive method and call it after send method??

Comment: Yeah. Or you can use one more button to call the receive method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have my IDE with me right now, but you could try it with a AsyncTask and its `onPostExecute Callback` like this:

```
//method in your Activity/Fragment to recieve data
    private void askServer(String... params){
        Search searcher = new Search(){
            public void onPostExecute(String response){
                //this method is called on UI-Thread when the Asynctask is finished
                //check response for errors
                if(response.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error on response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    //handle your response eg fill a textView etc pp

                }
            }
        }

        searcher.execute
    }

    //Your Asynctask
    public class Search() extends Asynctask<String, Void, String>{

        doInBackground(String param){
            String response = "";
                try{
                    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/search.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                    //add your data
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat1",param[0].trim()));




                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //Execute HTTP Post Request

                    response= httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);



                }catch(Exception e){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return response;
    }
```

Also have a look at the [DOCU](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

And this great tutorial page [LINK](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: where shall i add receive data?? your program only shows where to add send data but nothing about receive. Also there is nothing about it in the tutorial.

Comment: The Method onPostExecute is called when the data is recieved with your response String

Comment: So, i should add this above code after the send code??

Comment: Sorry I do not really get what you are trying? With my code above, you are able te send data to a server, which processes the data and returns a result as json => (request is done) the asynctask is done and the onPostExecute method is called, there you can do your UI stuff. Please read some tutorials about `android server requests with asynctask` and you should manage it. It is really recommnded to understand copied code and try to get into it, then you are able to code your needs

Comment: i get it, asynctask is where i do the send part and onpostexecute, i do the receive part. I do the appropriate changes and will let you know.

Comment: Keep in mind that your logcat tells you that your php code has a failure `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Signature Ideal' and stones ='Single' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

For the search function, you do not have to make two web services in PHP for send and receive, for each search call the search web service which will print the result of search. In your php code you are printing 'search', replace it with results you got from database, get results from response in android code and show them instead of 'Search successful'.

If you do not want to make change into service, call the receive part after you send data and show the results in a thread which is run on UI thread.

Comment: can you show me where shall i change my php code?? sorry the php code was written by somebody else and i don't know php.

Comment: I can. But first edit question and add the response you are getting from server. It will be more helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the response from the logcat

Comment: First of all you have syntax problem in SQL query, resolve that. After resolving that, put this code after $queerexec = ...

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
{
    $json_output[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($json_output);

Use this code in your activity to get response:
response = client.execute(localHttpPost2);
entityr = response.getEntity();
is = entityr.getContent();reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
sb = new StringBuilder();
line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
sb.append(line);
}
is.close();
result = sb.toString();

Comment: The result variable will contain the response. Now get data from json and show the result. Hope that will help.

Comment: thanks, i will make appropriate change and let you know.